# data transfer between two angularjs controllers

Tags: angularjs, iframe, controllers

I want to change the iframe source on runtime

```
<div class="pp lsv-video pp-player" id="rs" ng-controller="ctrl2">
        <input type="text" style="width:0px;height:0px;display:none;"  />
        <iframe src="" class="lsv" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
```

when user clicks on any of the

(mentioned below), teh data mentioned b.VideoSrc should be transferred to the different controller Ctrl2 and iframe source has to be changed.

```
<ul ng-controller="ctrl1">
                        <li ng-repeat="b in KeynoteSessions | filter:isBD">
                            <a href='#rs' class="fancybox" name='{{b.VideoSrc}}'>
                                <img src='{{b.ImageSrc}}' width='{{b.ImageWidth}}' height='{{b.ImageHeight}}' alt='{{b.ImageAlt}}' /><br />
                                {{b.Text}}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

please help me to achieve this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways
1.You can create services and use common services to share data.
2.you can use rootscope variable.
3.angularjs  $emit, $broadcast methods you can use
like

```
myApp.factory('Data', function () {
    return { FirstName: '' };
});

myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
    $scope.Data = Data;
});

myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
    $scope.Data = Data;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/

check this one:[Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I'm putting related content in the same controller (Youtube frame and "remote" together for exemple) but sometime I can't, so I pass the data through a Javascript Variable ([Dont forget that your var need to be defined outside your controller](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) )